# converting a set to an arrayList with sorting operations

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have a `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>` and i want to get the list of keys as an ArrayList in an increasing order.

So for example my map:

```
Key|Value
2--->set1
1--->set2
5--->set3
```

I want to get the arraylist : [1,2,5]

```
public class Example {
     public static void main( String[] args ) {
         Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
         Set<Integer> set1 = Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(Collectors.toSet());
         Set<Integer> set2 = Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(Collectors.toSet());
         Set<Integer> set3 = Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(Collectors.toSet());
         map.put(2,set1);
         map.put(1,set2);
         map.put(5,set3);


         //what i have done:
         List<Integer> list = map.keySet()
                                 .stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
         list.sort((a,b)->a>b?b:a);
         System.out.println(list);

     }
}
```

This example do what i want, but i'm looking for a solution that make the sorting in the time of collecting the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `sorted` method:

```
List<Integer> list = map.keySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Or just `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet()); list.sort(null);`

Answer (score 1):

Even better, just change HashMap to TreeMap like this:

```
Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Quoting from docs "A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used." In case of Integers you will have natural order:)